# How to check the objects created in developer console?

Tags: javascript

I have the below script which creates a person object using constructor function.

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    var f = firstName;
    var l = lastName;
}
var person = new Person("a", "b");
```

When I check in developer console in chrome it does not show the person object created. How to check the same?

Comment: Why don't you try objectplayground.com , it will help you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[image: JS]**

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName= lastName;
}
var person = new Person("a", "b");
console.log(person)

window.x = person 
window.x.firstName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    var f = firstName;
    var l = lastName;
}
var person = new Person("a", "b");
console.log(person);
window.person = person
```

Comment: I want to inspect the object created

Comment: inspect can only html elements its JS how u do inspect @Sunil

Comment: Say i declare a variable x. In console i can use window.x to see the value. Similary how to check the values present in person. window.person is not working? @gayathri

Comment: Wehn you will do console.log(person) in the console tab under developer tools in chrome you will be able to inspect the structure of the person

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you create a new object in JavaScript. You need to create a constructor function variable. It can be an anonymous function or you can pass it already as arguments the properties that the new Object should have. After that, you call the constructor function (which is a sort of "mold" for your objects of that class) and pass it the particular values for your objects properties. In a nutshell, you'll have something like this:

```
var Car = function Car(color, model) {
            this.constructor;
            this.color = color;
            this.model = model;
}

var vehicle = new Vehicle;
vehicle.color = "red";
vehicle.model = "Honda 2002"

console.log(vehicle);
```

To understand in much more detail what is happening with objects and prototypes and constructors, please read this article here: https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword